# Selecting an overloaded function between two functions that both have a parameter of the type reference to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, overloading, braced-init-list

Here is a demonstrative program where there are declared two functions that both accept a reference to an array.

```
#include <iostream>

void f( const int ( &a )[5] )
{
    std::cout << "void f( const int ( &a )[5] )\n";
}

void f( const int ( &a )[6] )
{
    std::cout << "void f( const int ( &a )[6] )\n";
}

int main() 
{
    f( { 1, 2, 3 } );
    
    return 0;
}
```

As it is seen the first function declaration is

```
void f( const int ( &a )[5] );
```

and the second function declarations is

```
void f( const int ( &a )[6] );
```

And the function call expression is

```
f( { 1, 2, 3 } );
```

Trying to compile this program using the compiler `C++14 (gcc 8.3)` at www,ideone.com I get the error

```
prog.cpp:15:17: error: call of overloaded ‘f(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’ is ambiguous
  f( { 1, 2, 3 } );
                 ^
prog.cpp:3:6: note: candidate: ‘void f(const int (&)[5])’
 void f( const int ( &a )[5] )
      ^
prog.cpp:8:6: note: candidate: ‘void f(const int (&)[6])’
 void f( const int ( &a )[6] )
```

Is the program incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program is correct. It is a bug of the compiler.

According to the C++ 14 Standard (13.3.3.2 Ranking implicit conversion sequences)

> 3 Two implicit conversion sequences of the same form are
> indistinguishable conversion sequences unless one of the following
> rules applies:
>
> (3.1) — List-initialization sequence L1 is a better conversion
> sequence than list-initialization sequence L2 if
>
> (3.1.2) — L1 converts to type “array of N1 T”, L2 converts to type
> “array of N2 T”, and N1 is smaller than N2, even if one of the other
> rules in this paragraph would otherwise apply.

Thus according to the quote the overloaded function

```
void f( const int ( &a )[5] );
```

will be called.

Answer (score 1):

some compilers may give a warning at

> `f( { 1, 2, 3 } );`

that call to function f is ambiguous. but the program should compile.
and it will call the overloaded function `void f( const int ( &a )[5] );` as long as function call contains array of length <=5.
as soon as you introduce the 6th element in the array it will call `void f( const int ( &a )[6] );`
also to mention passed argument as `a` is unused in both the definitions. if you got no use of that argument then the below definition shall also work.

```
void f( const int ( & )[5] ){}
```